# How to Iterate over a list of numpy arrays in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I currently have a list of numpy arrays. These arrays contain sets of 2D points. I'd like to iterate over each array in this list as depending on the contents of the array two scenarios can occur. The issue I'm running into is that when I try to iterate over the list like so:

`for array in list:`

it iterates over entries in the arrays as opposed to iterating over the arrays themselves. For example:

```
a = [array([[[1, 2]], [[3, 4]]], dtype=int32), array([[[5, 6]], [[7, 8)]]], dtype=int32)]
for array in a:
   print(array)
```

yields

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

when I'm expecting to get

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to reproduce. Here's my code and I'm getting the output you expect.

import numpy as np
a = [np.array([[[1, 2]], [[3, 4]]], dtype=np.int32), np.array([[[5, 6]], [[7, 8]]], dtype=np.int32)]
for i in a:
    print(i)

[[[1 2]]

 [[3 4]]]
[[[5 6]]

 [[7 8]]]

Comment: After fixing the syntax error in the example you gave, I cannot reproduce what you describe.

Comment: As a side note, please don't import names `from` np, especially if you're going to want to use them for other variables. Writing `for array in a:` in your sample makes `array` stop referring to the Numpy type and will mess up subsequent code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.squeeze` to remove one dimension and use `.tolist()` to print in the format you want.

```
a = [array([[[1, 2]], [[3, 4]]], dtype=int32),array([[[5, 6]], [[7, 8]]], dtype=int32)]
for array in a:
  print(squeeze(array).tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one too many brackets on each array as needed for your results

```
a = [array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=int32), array([[5, 6], [7, 8]], dtype=int32)]
for array in a:
   print(squeeze(array).tolist())
```

still produces

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```